# Typesetting the numbered mathematical formula in latex

Tags: latex

How to typeset the following numbered mathematical formula:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `cases` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Delta(x) = \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
    -1 & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
     0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$
\Delta(x)= 
    \left\{ 
        \begin{matrix}
            1  & \mathrm{if}~x>0  \\ 
            -1 & \mathrm{if}~x<0  \\ 
            0  & \mathrm{otherwise}
        \end{matrix}
    \right.
$
```

Which produces the equation you wanted like this:

[The example LaTeX equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAqT7.png)

This type of equation has a few key tricks in it:

1. The left bracket has to be declared as `\{` in order for LaTeX to
   know to display it since it is a special character
2. Also, the left brace has to be resized to match however many rows you include in your equation, which is done by the `\left` command preceding it.  This can also be done for `(`, `[`, etc.
3. Since you have a `\left` command, it has to be accompanied by a `\right}`, but you don't want to display the right brace, so the `\right.` ends the section without displaying the right brace.
4. The `\mathrm` command turns the text inside it back to normal text (removing the math mode temporarily) so that your "if" and "otherwise" aren't italicized.
5. The `~` just adds a little space so that your "if" doesn't collide with the `x > 0`, which often happens when using `mathrm`

Alternatively, you can check out [this post for other ways to write piecewise functions in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside).  I hope this helps.